# Modifying only changed elements with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to draw a grid of rectangles on a page.

There is an array that determines the color of each cell in the grid. Sometimes, elements of this array are updated to change their color.

Is there a d3 pattern or method to change only specific elements? I have a render function that re-renders the entire grid in d3, but I don't want to iterate over (and change the fill of) every rect element when only a few cells change color, as there could be thousands of cells.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the source and there doesn't seem to be. If performance was an issue, what I would do on every `.enter` call, is track any changes myself by setting a custom `.attr('data-lastColor')`. On every `.data` update call after that, I would do

```
.data(dataSet)
.attr('color', function(d){ 
    var theElement = d3(this);
    var newColor;

    //set the new color here, under whatever conditions you want
    if (foo==bar) { 
        newColor = 'green' 
    } else {
        newColor = 'red'
    } 

    if theElement.attr('data-lastColor') != newColor {
        theElement.attr('color') = newColor;
        theElement.attr('data-lastColor') = newColor;
    } else {
        //Don't do anything if the new color is the same as this color, saving valuable computing time
    }
})
```

Sorry if the answer was a bit rough around the edges, but it should do what you want :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. It's almost strange that d3 doesn't have a way of "binding" to the dataset. I'll just add a dirty bit to the points I'll change.